# How to merge two lists into one list in python

Tags: python, list

I am wondering how to merge two lists of lists into one list of lists.
For example, there are two lists of lists shown below:

```
A=[[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]
B=[[8],[9],[1],[10],[11]]
```

And the list that I want is shown belwo:

```
C=[[2,8],[3,9],[4,1],[5,10],[6,11]]
```

Appreciate a lot if any advices and if I do not make my question clear, please let me know, I am open to change it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Hint: Use a list comprehension and `zip()`.

Comment: Hint:  use `zip`

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, I tried to use the command pd.concat, but the result is not what I want.

Comment: @Chris_Rands when I replied to Scott, I did not see any comments here.Please!

Comment: Maybe you didn't use `pd.concat` properly; hard to say as you haven't posted it.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zip` and `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
list(map(list, map(chain.from_iterable, zip(A,B))))
```

output: `[[2, 8], [3, 9], [4, 1], [5, 10], [6, 11]]`

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be something like this

```
A = [[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]
B = [[8],[9],[1],[10],[11]]

C = []

for i in range(len(A)):
    C.append(A[i] + B[i])
```

This would depend on your A and B lists being the same length however!

Comment: You should use `zip` rather than iterate on the indices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **list comprehension**.

```
A = [[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]
B = [[8],[9],[1],[10],[11]]

C =[ i[0]+i[1] for i in zip(A,B)]       
print(C)
```

**Output**

```
C=[[2,8],[3,9],[4,1],[5,10],[6,11]]
```